# Yacc cannot be used in Centos6.4

Tags: centos6

I have installed centos6.4 in vmware, but it cannot use Yacc command.
I googled it but cannot find the answer.
Is there anybody knows it? thanks

Comment: it would help if you said specifically what the problem with using `yacc` is? What is the error message you get? How do you envoke it to get the error message, and what behaviour you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.I know I'm just curious of yacc isn't used in centos6.4.

Answer (score 0):

How about using byacc instead?

Byacc (Berkeley Yacc) is a public domain LALR parser generator which
is used by many programs during their build process.

If you are going to do development on your system, you will want to install

If it's not installed then running the following should install it:

yum install -y byacc

Comment: Note that the `byacc` package is the one which `yum provides /usr/bin/yacc`